# a word to describe an increase of communication on forum

Tags: word-choice

Let's say there is an on-line forum, on which its members have regular communication. The communication hasn't been too active recently. Only two or three messages a day. But the day before yesterday Jack posted a question about cats that made the communication on the forum very active: 25 messages the day before yesterday, 35 messages yesterday, and 20 today. What would be the best idiomatic way to describe this happening in English in the following sentence:

Jack caused a little ____________________ on our forum when he posted his question about cats the day before yesterday.

Comment: "Fellowship" isn't the correct word. It means a feeling of community or comradeship within a group, something that cannot measurably increase because because of a brief flurry of activity.

"Brief flurry of activity" might be the term you're looking for though :)

Comment: @gotube - Thank you! So, what word should I use in my question instead of "fellowship"?

Comment: "Communication" sounds right. How is the term you're looking for different from "communication"?

Comment: @gotube - Good! Thank you. I'll change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jack caused a little **"stir"**.

stir (noun) - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stir)

- a state of disturbance, agitation, or brisk activity
- widespread notice and discussion : IMPRESSION

> the book caused quite a stir

I think **"[commotion](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commotion)"** could fit too.